# How to create link in magento 2

Tags: magento2, link

I need to create a link like

> http:// base_url / storeId / productID?q

how do I correctly specify `storeId / productID`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that natively, there is no URL constructed like this :

`base_url/ storeId/productID?q`

---

**About the STORE :**

To set store in URL, you can add this : `?___store=storecode` (?+3 underscores)

Example : `https://domaine.com/?___store=fr`

---

**About the PRODUCT :**

You should understand that in Magento, the product page url is constructed like this :

```
https://domaine.com/catalog/product/view/id/1043
```

the `1043` is the product id, and Magento Rewrite this URL in a pretty one like this :

```
https://domaine.com/catalog/sweet-shirt-miroo.html
```

So you understood, to get your URL as you need, you have to do some stuff to rewrite the native Magento URL to the yours.

I hope it clarified the way.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn’t understand what to do. I'm a newbie. I need that in one link the id of the store and the product is transmitted. more examples are possible. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a module that inserts a button on the product page and by clicking on this button I need to go to a third-party application. The link that the button should transmit to the third-party application storeId and productId.

Comment: @AnyaMoroz based off of this comment, you can in that case grab store ID by `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface#getStore()#getId()` and the product ID by `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface#getId()` - you can then do something similar to `sprintf('http://my-prefix/%u/%u', $storeId, $productId)` to grab a formatted URL. You'll need to figure out how it is most appropriate to get instances of both classes as we can't help you further with the information you've provided.